# How to scroll ads by openx in a certain time interval?

Tags: php, openx

I am a beginner in openx.I need to change the ads every 10 seconds in my site.I see that the ads change if I reload the browser.I tried to reload the browser every 10 seconds to change ads via javasccript but it took a while to reload the page and this happened every 10 seconds so there is no site to see.
I have figured out that the javascript for the openx ads is created in ajs.php.I am thinking about editing some codes there.But before I do something stupid and render this site useless.I want to know if there is another better way to change the ads(rather scroll) every 10 secs.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with OpenX's iframe tags:

```
<!--/* OpenX iFrame Tag v2.8.9 */-->

<iframe id='a123456' name='a123456' src='http://www.yourdomain.com/www/delivery/afr.php?refresh=10&amp;zoneid=1' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' width='728' height='90'><a href='http://www.yourdomain.com/www/delivery/ck.php?n=a123456' target='_blank'><img src='http://www.yourdomain.com/www/delivery/avw.php?zoneid=1&amp;n=a123456' border='0' alt='' /></a></iframe>
```

If you use the invocation code generator there's a field called "Refresh" which will cause the zone to refresh every X seconds.

Comment: Be more descriptive about your solution. Please read:[How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer).